# React/Ruby on Rails: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') when passing down mapped prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ruby-on-rails, dictionary

I've been really pulling my hair out over this bug as I've been troubleshooting it for the past few days and haven't found any reliable answers.

My goal is to be able to route to an individual component, [http://localhost:4000/hris/employees/1] and show that individual 'employee' card on a routed page.

In my **App.js** component, I *believe* I have everything routed properly:

```
<Route exact path="/hris/employees">
            <Employees 
              employees={employees}
              setEmployees={setEmployees}
              addresses={addresses}
              setAddresses={setAddresses}
              zips={zips}
              setZips={setZips}
              skills={skills}
              setSkills={setSkills}
              onSubmitNewEmployee={onSubmitNewEmployee}
              onSubmitNewSkill={onSubmitNewSkill}
              onSubmitNewAddress={onSubmitNewAddress}
              displayCard={displayCard}
              setDisplayCard={setDisplayCard}
            />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/hris/employees/:id">
            <Employee />
          </Route>
```

Then here is the **Employees.js** component:

```
import React from "react"
import Employee from './Employee'
import EmployeeForm from './EmployeeForm'

function Employees({
    employees,
    setEmployees,
    addresses,
    setAddresses,
    zips,
    setZips,
    skills,
    setSkills,
    onShowDetails,
    displayCard,
    setDisplayCard
}) {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Employees</h1>
                <br/>
                <div className="card-container">
                    <div className="cards">
                        {employees.length > 0 ? 
                            employees.map(employee =>
                                <Employee
                                    key={employee.id}
                                    employee={employee}
                                    test={console.log(employee.id)}
                                />) : null }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <EmployeeForm
                        employees={employees}
                        setEmployees={setEmployees}
                        addresses={addresses}
                        setAddresses={setAddresses}
                        zips={zips}
                        setZips={setZips}
                        skills={skills}
                        setSkills={setSkills}
                        onShowDetails={onShowDetails}
                        displayCard={displayCard}
                        setDisplayCard={setDisplayCard}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Employees
```

The important code to look at here is the following:

```
<div className="card-container">
                    <div className="cards">
                        {employees.length > 0 ? 
                            employees.map(employee =>
                                <Employee
                                    key={employee.id}
                                    employee={employee}
                                    test={console.log(employee.id)}
                                />) : null }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

With this, the `<Employee />` component is then mapped out and the data appears perfectly fine in the `<Employees />` component with each card populating within the `<div className="cards">...</div>` . Please see the following image as an example:

[Employees Component, Employee Map Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pQoc.png)

When I `console.log(employee.id)` within the `test` prop in Employee, I get the following log:

[Console Log looking good!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U6aB.png)

When I go into Postman, the route works fine too!

HOWEVER, once I'm in the `<Employee />` component, here are the code and the issues I receive:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Employee({
    employee,
    test
}) {
    
    console.log(employee.id)
    console.log(test)
    const data = employee.skills
    const listSkills = data.map((data) => <li key={data.skill_name}>{data.skill_name}</li>)

    return (
        <div className="card-spacing">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-details">
                    <ul className="cards-ul">
                        <li className="card-li">
                            <div>
                            <Link to={`/employees/${employee.id}`}></Link>
                            <div>
                                <h3>{employee.first_name} {employee.middle_name} {employee.last_name} {employee.suffix}</h3>
                                <p><>Role:</> <>{employee.job_title}</></p>
                                <p><>Contact Info:</><br/><>Phone: <><ul>{employee.emp_phone}</ul></></><>Email: </><ul>{employee.emp_email}</ul></p>
                                <p><>Address:</><br/><ul><>{employee.address.line_one}, {employee.address.line_two}</><br/><>{employee.address.zip.city}, {employee.address.zip.state} {employee.address.zip.zip_code}</></ul></p>
                                <p><>Gender: </>{employee.gender}</p>
                                <p><>SSN/Tax ID: </> ***-**-{employee.tax_number.slice(7, 11)}</p>
                                <p>Start Date: {employee.start_date}</p>
                                <p>Compensation: {employee.hourly_or_salary}</p>
                                <p>Hourly-Rate: ${employee.hourly_rate}</p>
                                <p>Annual-Salary: ${employee.annual_salary}</p>
                                <p>PTO Policy: <br/><ul><>{employee.pto_policy}</></ul></p>
                                <div>Skills: <br/><ul>{listSkills}</ul></div>
                                <p>Notes: <br/>{employee.emp_notes}</p>
                                <br/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-buttons">
                                <button>Edit</button>
                                <button>Expand/Collapse</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Employee
```

This data within the `return ()` works perfectly when in [localhost:4000/hris/employees], but in this current situation, but I keep receiving the following error after console.logging my issue and checking the [localhost:4000/hris/employees/1] route:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

and

```
The above error occurred in the <Employee> component:
```

I'm floored because I've done this a ton of times before and have never run into this before. The map should work fine.

I've tried doing the following to no avail:
`employees.map(employee =>`  (the "standard")
`employees.map(employeeMap =>` 
`employees && employees.map(employee =>` 
`employees && employees.map(employeeMap =>` 
`employees?.map(employee =>`
`employees?.map(employeeMap =>`
`employees && employees?map(employee =>` 
`employees && employees?map(employeeMap =>`

Could anybody provide some context? Thanks!

Comment: 1) you are not passing any props to the Employee component when using it with the dynamic route 2) additionally, you are not retrieving the `:id` from the route params.  3) there is no way for the Employee component to have an entire `employee` object without retrieving it from somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Randy! You led me to figuring out the right approach!

Answer (score 1):

@randy-casburn (https://stackoverflow.com/users/9078341/randy-casburn) led me to answer the question by giving me the context to ask ChatGPT the right question.

What I was able to do was .map() from App.js and create a map of all the individual employee components. I was able to use the following code in my routes to fix:

```
            {employees.map((employee) => (
              <Route exact path={`/hris/employees/${employee.id}`} key={employee.id}>
                <Employee 
                  employee={employee}
                />
              </Route>
            ))}
```

Much easier than anticipated. Thanks!